# R : How to Plot a Zoomed in Map of a City

Tags: r, maps, mapping

Is there a way to (or what is the best way to) plot a map of a specific city, along with roads or neighborhood outlines?

I am pretty new to using R, so I've done a bit of Googling for an answer, but the ones I come up with don't work too well:

With ggmap, it appears I'd have to pay to get a good map. This is probably fine for me, but I'd be curious to see if there's a free way, such as with the maps package.  I tried mapping a city (Minneapolis) with the maps package, but it came back with an error which I can't figure out how to get rid of, either through experimenting or Googling for help.  Below is the code I did:

```
Minnesota <- subset(states, region %in% c("minnesota"))
```

which just kept coming back with **Error: object 'states' not found**.  This was my first attempt to bring up a map of which I could zoom in on using the maps package. Does this mean maps didn't install correctly? Or is there something I'm missing?

I also tried using map, which I believe is part of ggplot2, with the code below:

```
map(database = "state", xlim = c(-93.0, -94.0), ylim = c(44.5, 45.5))
```

Again, this was to try and get a zoomed in map of a particular city, Minneapolis, but I kept getting the error "all data out of bounds".  I assumed this was because the coordinates I entered were incorrect, but they line up with the coordinates of the city.  What does it mean that all data is out of bounds?

The last thing I tried was using the package rworldmap.  With the code below:

```
minneapolis <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(minneapolis, xlim = c(-93, -94), ylim = c(44.5, 45.5))
```

I think this one was actually working, the problem is that it's so zoomed in that I can't see the borders that come with the package/plot.  Would there be a way to add roads/neighborhood borders to a map like this one?  It seems like that would be the best way for me to build a map for free, but maybe I'm wrong.

Thank you for any help and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the map to be interactive, then you should consider  using [leaflet](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), You can check this [tutorial](https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/Notebooks/InteractiveMaps.nb.html).

If you want it to be static ggmap or tmap are good options.

You do no need to pay. You can access the goole api or the OSM api and get the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I looked through it and started going through the tutorial, and it looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you again, this was very meaningful to me.